# EF6 Version error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using EF6 but got this error Assembly 'TBLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Answer (score 0):

You have to uninstall related packages and re-install them by using  [package manager console](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/Package-Manager-Console)